# Profile link in people search results not encoded

Tags: 2013, user-profile, people-search

I'm using Forms Based Auth using the SQLMembership provider and all seems to be working fine except for viewing user profiles from people search results.

The search is creating linkw like:

```
http://<sitename>/my/sites/Person.aspx?accountname=i:0#.f|sql_membership|<accountName>
```

resulting in a user not found error. If I url encode the same link and paste into the address bar it works. It appears to the the `#` that is causing the problem. If I replace this with a `%23` if works.

i.e.:

```
http://<sitename>/my/sites/Person.aspx?accountname=i:0%23.f|sql_membership|<accountName>
```

Does anyone know of a work around for this?

Comment: I have the same problem!! Could you solved it? Best Regards Carlos.

Comment: Check this, it should be fixed in Sept 2014 CU

http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97882/my-sites-link-in-search-resuls-is-incorrect-escaped

Answer (score 0):

The September 9,2014 Update didn't solve this issue in my environment. The patch version is now at 15.0.4649.1001.

I found this [workaround](http://thesharepointfarm.com/2014/06/workaround-ms14-022-double-encoding-bug/) and solved this issue.